# tar.gzファイルを解凍中にエラー「not in gzip format」が発生する

Tags: gzip, tar

Dockerfileからimgaeをビルドする際、以下のところでエラーが出ます。

**Dockerfile**

```
RUN curl -LJO https://github.com/rasyomon/sourcecode/releases/download/v${LEAN_VERSION}/Leantime-v${LEAN_VERSION}.tar.gz && \
tar -zxvf Leantime-v${LEAN_VERSION}.tar.gz --strip-components 1 && \
rm Leantime-v${LEAN_VERSION}.tar.gz
```

**エラーの内容**

```
[ 7/15] RUN curl -LJO https://github.com/rasyomon/sourcecode/releases/download/v2.1.8/Leantime-v2.1.8.tar.gz &&     tar -zxvf Leantime-v2.1.8.tar.gz --strip-components 1 &&     rm Leantime-v2.1.8.tar.gz:
#10 0.338   % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
#10 0.338                                  Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100     9  100     9    0     0     17      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--    17
#10 0.858
#10 0.858 gzip: stdin: not in gzip format
#10 0.858 tar: Child returned status 1
#10 0.858 tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c curl -LJO https://github.com/rasyomon/sourcecode/releases/download/v${LEAN_VERSION}/Leantime-v${LEAN_VERSION}.tar.gz &&     tar -zxvf Leantime-v${LEAN_VERSION}.tar.gz --strip-components 1 &&     rm Leantime-v${LEAN_VERSION}.tar.gz]: exit code: 2
```

ネットで調べたところgzip形式ではないということなので
`wget https://github.com/Leantime/leantime/releases/download/v2.1.8/Leantime-v2.1.8.tar.gz`
を実行し、fileコマンドでファイルを調べたところ
`Leantime-v2.1.8.tar.gz: gzip compressed data, from Unix, original size modulo 2^32 98795520`
と出てきました。

どのようにしたらエラーを解決できるでしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### 問題点

- Dockerfile で指定しているダウンロード URL は、そもそも
  リポジトリ (`https://github.com/rasyomon/sourcecode/`) が 404 Not Found の状態です。
- wget で指定している URL は正しいようですが、こちらの URL はリダイレクトを挟むので (この実行方法だと) 結果が HTML ファイルとして保存されてしまっています。

#### 対応方法

Dockerfile の RUN コマンドで指定する URL を、正しいものに修正してみてください。

```
RUN curl -LJO https://github.com/Leantime/leantime/releases/download/v${LEAN_VERSION}/Leantime-v${LEAN_VERSION}.tar.gz && \
tar -xzvf Leantime-v${LEAN_VERSION}.tar.gz --strip-components 1 && \
rm Leantime-v${LEAN_VERSION}.tar.gz
```

---

補足として、`tar` コマンドにおける引数の扱いは少し特殊で、本来なら1つ目の引数のみ `c`, `x`, `t` いずれかのように順番が決まっています。(2つ目以降は他の一般的なコマンドと同じく順不同)

解凍 (展開) したい場合には、`xzvf` のように `x` を先頭に指定する必要があります。